# Free MPEG cutting/cropping/editing tool

Tags: video, editing, mpeg

I'm looking for a free tool to cut MPEG's that are created by recording from a USB cable receiver.

There are a number of applications that do this, and some are free, but most of them take the video and audio decoded and pass them into a codec again to write the final output.

I already have the MPEG's encoded the way I like, so what I need is a tool that can strip the beginning and the ending of the recording before and optionally commercial breaks, by rearranging the data within the file, not re-encoding it.

Now I'm using some old software that came with the cable-receiver, but this actually re-encodes the video when exporting. I've tried VirtualDub but had major trouble getting the audio and video streams to stay in sync (and this was also re-encoding)...

I found [this](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-Dub.htm) which comes pretty close, but doesn't allow much accuracy in selecting cut positions.

Answer (score 2):

By far, IMHO, the best thing to use for cutting video snips is the COMPLETELY FREEWARE  [AviDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)  for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the slicing is to be done,
these [split](https://superuser.com/questions/31135/split-mpeg-video-from-command-line) and [trim](https://superuser.com/questions/21736/how-to-trim-or-delete-parts-of-an-mpeg-video-from-the-linux-command-line) questions should help.

Answer (score 0):

Quicktime Pro can do this, although it is not really free.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/) a whirl?  I think it'll do what you're looking for, though I've never used it.